# Salesforce DX: Use namespaces for unlocked packages

Tags: salesforcedx

I recently discovered Salesforce DX and all related tools (e.g. CLI, DevHub, Scratch Orgs, etc). The Salesforce DX trails and the DX Developer Guides namespaces mention, that I can organize my meta-data with a ["namespace per app/package"](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_plan_namespaces.htm?search_text=Namespace).

So as I understand the resources, I do not have one namespace **per org** but every package can deploy its own namespace. I consulted the documentation for the [Project Configuration File](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev2gp_config_file.htm), the `force:package:create` and `force:package:version:create` command documentation but could not find any option to set the actual namespace for my app.

As I understand it, the namespace in the `sfdx-project.json` is only necessary (and available) if my DevHub has a namespace. It applies to all packages within the project.

How do I set namespaces for my packages?

Answer (score 3):

You need to do two things

1. You need to register the namespace that you want to use with your Dev Hub.

> Complete these tasks before you link a namespace.
>
> - If you don’t have an org with a registered namespace, create a
>     Developer Edition org that is separate from the Dev Hub or scratch
>     orgs. If you already have an org with a registered namespace, go to
>     Step 1.
> - In the Developer Edition org, create and register the
>     namespace.
>
> **Important** Choose namespaces carefully. If you’re trying out
>   this feature or need a namespace for testing purposes, choose a
>   disposable namespace. Don’t choose a namespace that you want to use in
>   the future for a production org or some other real use case. Once you
>   associate a namespace with an org, you can't change it or reuse it.
>
> 1. Log in to your Dev Hub org as the System Administrator or as a user
>      with the Salesforce DX Namespace Registry permissions.
> 2. If
>      you have not already done so, define and deploy a My Domain name.
>
> **Tip**
>   Why do you need a My Domain? A My Domain adds a subdomain to your
>   Salesforce org URL so that it’s unique. As part of the Namespace
>   Registry linking process, you’ll be logging into two distinct orgs
>   simultaneously (your Dev Hub org and your Developer Edition org), and
>   your browser can’t reliably distinguish between the two without a My
>   Domain.
>
> You receive an email when your domain name is ready for testing. It
>   can take a few minutes.
>
> 3. From the App Launcher menu, select Namespace Registries.
> 4. Click Link
>      Namespace.
>
> **Tip** Make sure your browser allows pop-ups from your Dev Hub
>   org.
>
> 5. Log in to the Developer Edition org in which your namespace is
>      registered using the org's System Administrator's credentials.
>
> We
>   recommend that you link Developer Edition orgs with a registered
>   namespace to only a single Dev Hub org. You cannot link orgs without a
>   namespace, sandboxes, scratch orgs, patch orgs, and branch orgs to the
>   Namespace Registry.
>
> To view all the namespaces linked to the Namespace Registry, select
>   the All Namespace Registries view.

Source: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_reg_namespace.htm

2. Then, you need to refer to that namespace in your `sfdx-project.json`

Example from https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev2gp_config_file.htm, with added namespace, `my_ns`, in the first line after the `{`:

```
{
   "namespace": "my_ns",
   "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
   "sourceApiVersion": "43.0",
   "packageDirectories": [
      {
         "path": "util",
         "default": true,
         "package": "Expense Manager - Util",
         "versionName": "Spring ‘18",
         "versionDescription": "Welcome to Spring 2018 Release of Expense Manager Util Package",
         "versionNumber": "4.7.0.NEXT",
         "definitionFile": "config/scratch-org-def.json"
      },
      {
         "path": "exp-core",
         "default": false,
         "package": "Expense Manager",
         "versionName": "v 3.2",
         "versionDescription": "Spring 2018 Release",
         "versionNumber": "3.2.0.NEXT",
         "definitionFile": "config/scratch-org-def.json",
         "dependencies": [
            {
               "package": "Expense Manager - Util",
               "versionNumber": "4.7.0.LATEST"

            },
            {
               "package" : "External Apex Library - 1.0.0.4"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "packageAliases": [
      { "Expense Manager - Util": "0HoB00000004CFpKAM" },
      { "External Apex Library - 1.0.0.4": "04tB0000000IB1EIAW" },
      { "Expense Manager": "0HoB00000004CFuKAM" }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Could I have an org with multiple unlocked packages in it, with different namespaces for each of those packages?                                                                                                                                or do i go with 1 sandbox per unlocked package, since only 1 namespace can be set at sandbox org level, when working in an enterprise setup with enterprise/unlimited edition?